# Can anyone recommend a good tutorial for XAMARIN Forms (3.3/4) integration with SignalR for chat purposes?

Tags: xamarin, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

It seems that most of the content out there is out of date for XAMARIN with SignalR integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one tutorial from James Montemagno: https://montemagno.com/real-time-communication-for-mobile-with-signalr/